# ListView not adding a valid string

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm making a console terminal using ListView for my custom server.

It writes any string that was given to it from the same class `Main` but refuses if its from another `Misc`.

[Heres a gif of the following code in action](https://gyazo.com/10f606dd379e3943d69ee3faa8c5e0a3)

The first part of the gif is from `myFunction()`. As you can see, the messagebox shows that `str` in `stringToConsole()` contains a string("report 1" and "report 2") but it **wouldnt** add it.

Second part of the gif is from `Execute_Click` event. As you can see, again the messagebox shows that `str` in `stringToConsole()` contains a string(whatever i type) and it **would** add it

### Following code is in Class `Misc`.

**Following code's strings are not able to be added.**

```
public static string myFunction()
    {
        Main myClass = new Main();
        myClass.stringToConsole("report 1", "ConsoleList");

        Thread.Sleep(2000); // emulate work

        myClass.stringToConsole("report 2", "ConsoleList");
        return "string";
    }
```

### Following codes are inside the form class `Main`.

```
private void startupProcedure()
    {
        label1.Text = Misc.myFunction();
    }
```

**This add strings to the `ListView`(Console List)**

```
 public void stringToConsole(string str, string destination)
    {
        if (destination == "ConsoleList")
        {
            // to check if str has a value
            MessageBox.Show(str); // string does have a value
            ConsoleList.Items.Add(str); // refuse to use str from myFunction()
        }
    }
```

**Following code's strings are able to be added.**

```
private void Execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        executeCommandLine(CommandLine.Text, "ConsoleList");
        CommandLine.Clear();
    }

public void executeCommandLine(string commandLine, string destination)
    {
        stringToConsole(commandLine, destination); // this shows in Listview
    }
```

Comment: Your code example is not complete, we cannot tell you exactly what's wrong. Post **all** the relevant code, for example how you call Execute_Click

Comment: Execute_click is an event handler for a button Execute. are you new to Winforms? everything is there

Comment: `Main myClass = new Main();`  is always making a new class.  I'm guessing you are expecting it to refer to your current instance, but it isn't.  Also `Also watch the Gif. maybe that will help your ignorant ass to understand` isn't a good way to get help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very similar question was asked some hours ago. You have a very, very basic problem:

```
Main myClass = new Main();
```

You are instantiating a new Main form, however, you are never showing it or using it outside the function's scope, hence, you are not modifying the Main instance you want to modify.

An easy way to do this would be to pass the Main instance to the function:

```
public static string myFunction(Main formInstance)
{
    formInstance.stringToConsole("report 1", "ConsoleList");

    Thread.Sleep(2000); // emulate work

    formInstance.stringToConsole("report 2", "ConsoleList");
    return "string";
}

private void startupProcedure()
{
    label1.Text = Misc.myFunction(this);
}
```

Comment: ok. so is it possible to do what im doing without being in the same class?